# How to pass a method as a callback function in another method?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am creating a server for Rage MP, which is a client application for the online game GTA 5. To achieve this, I am using a bootstrapper to create a C# server. My goal is to create custom attributes that allow me to add authentication checks before calling events triggered from the client-side.

I use the method  `NAPI.ClientEvent.Register` to handle some events created from my custom attribute. However, I want to use reflection to check if a method has my custom attribute Authorized, and if it does, I want to call the method when using my custom attribute.

```cs
using System.Reflection;

using GTANetworkAPI;


namespace someScripts 
{
    class RageScript : Script
    {
        public RageScript()
        {
             MethodInfo[] methods = GetType().GetMethods();

             foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
             {
                 EventHandlerAttribute attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<EventHandlerAttribute>();

                 if (attribute != null)
                 {
                      RegisterEvent(attribute.EventName, method)
                 };
             }

        }



        public void RegisterEvent(string eventName, MethodInfo method)
        {


            MethodInfo handleMethod = GetType().GetMethod("HandleEvent");

            NAPI.ClientEvent.Register(handleMethod, eventName, this) ;
        }

        public void HandleEvent(Player player, string str )
        {
            
        }

    }

}
```

So, in the Register method, there is a certain structure in the parameters.

```
public void Register(MethodInfo method, string eventName, object classInstance);
```

I want to call HandleEvent when an event is triggered from the client-side, and then check if the method has a custom attribute Authenticated. If it doesn't, I'll call the method directly. If it does have the attribute, I'll check the player's authentication and then call the method.

As you noticed, the Register method does not have the capability to provide a delegate and action directly.

I have read more documentation to resolve this problem, but unfortunately, I have not found a solution yet.

Finally, the result that I want to achieve is:

```cs
namespace SomeScripts2{
   class AdminEvents : RageScript
   {
      [EventHandler("create_vehicle")]
      [Authorized] // If the user is not authorized, the method will not be called
      public void OnCreateVehicle(Player player, string nameVehicle){
              //....some code 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should always register a *dispatcher* method that would in turn call another according your metrics.

Comment: @aybe I want to add some code in ```HandleEvent``` and include a parameter called ```method``` to implement logic for checking authorization. As you can see, the Register method calls the method with specific parameters. How can I add my own parameters to this method call?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot modify its signature unless you modify the API itself, which isn't possible. But that's not a problem; store whatever state you will need in the encompassing class and use it from within the method. If you don't manage the lifetime of the script, thus, the state won't be persistent, you could for instance have a static field that would store the data you need to access.

Comment: @aybe Maybe you have an example or a link to the documentation? Could you provide me with more information?

Comment: I posted an example, adjust as you see fit.